# start d3-svg-annotation application

Tags: angular, d3.js, annotations

I am trying to run d3-svg-annotation library with angular. but there is no angular-cli file. even I tried with npm start which is written in script in package.json. but still, I am not getting any success. any idea how to start this application, because I want to extend it and it is written in the documents, but they haven't given any specifications to run this app.

I am using this library for creating annotations: https://d3-annotation.susielu.com/

I took fork of this library and want to make some changes for customization. then, I want to run the app anyhow to check whether my app is running or not with my customizations. hope this clarifies my problem.

any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Which bit are you having trouble with? There are [lots](https://bl.ocks.org/susielu/974e41473737320f8db5ae711ded8542) [of](https://bl.ocks.org/emeeks/762b3694269a46151f73f6bc48be6d1c) [examples](https://bl.ocks.org/susielu/a464c24d8b42f0c4d9fafe7b48e9e60a) of d3-svg-annotation in action.

Comment: I took fork of this library and want to make some changes for customization. then, I want to run the app anyhow to check whether my app is running or not with my customizations. hope this clarifies my problem.

Comment: edit your question to add that as it will help others who read it.

Comment: it's done. hope this will help others to read and help me and others also.